# Please welcome your new Moderator team!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Yippie! Congrats all of you! I know you'll propel this site into awesomeness!

Comment: Great choice! This is the 3 I would have selected also!

Comment: Good luck!.....

Comment: 3 mods ?! I'm voting to close 2 of them as duplicates :D congrats !

Comment: Gratz to all new mods!

Comment: Congratulation to all three of you.

Answer (score 12):

Best of luck, and I know that all three of you will do very well at your job. Congratulations, and I hope to spend many an interesting meta/chat discussion with you three! =)

Comment: You bet! And thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if congratulations or condolences are in order...

But I look forward to working and arguing with Em C. They've been a positive influence on the site thus far and I'm sure they'll continue to be.

Good luck. You're gonna need it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to AJ and Tinkeringbell and welcome as our new moderators to join the excellent hard-working trio of Catija, HDE 226868 and John. You have all been making this site a better place and setting a really good example for every user.

I also consider that having 5 moderators now is a sure sign that IPS.SE is a thriving and growing online community with increasing participation and new users every day. At this rate I expect to see IPS successfully complete public beta in the near future.

Comment: There's no correlation between more moderators and graduation.

Comment: Only 3 moderators are usually appointed for beta sites. More moderators reflects a lot more site work and shows steadily increasing participation. And we can see that here. That tells me the site is heading in the right direction (towards graduation) -- do you disagree @Catija?

Comment: I do disagree. Many, many sites graduated with only three and still have only three. All it says is that this site has a lot of complicated content that needs special attention.

Comment: *"All it says is that this site has a lot of complicated content that needs special attention."* __ OK, I get it. Thanks for explaining that point @Catija.